# SQL Server: join one table with two table have same names but select all data from table first if available, otherwise from second table

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join, node-mssql

I tried searching this kind of use case on google but did found exact what i was looking so, Need help to reach to specific point by useful answer, docs or any reference

I have this situation: table A has to be joined with table B and table C; B and C have similar columns, so there will be duplicate column names in select part, however give preferences to all the data of tables B if available otherwise show data from table c

For example:

```
SELECT 
    ae.*, ml.name as name, ml.contact AS contact,
    ve.name AS name, ve.contact AS contact
FROM 
    TABLE ae
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE ml ON ae.eid = ml.eid
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLE ve ON ae.eid = ve.eid
WHERE
    ae.eid = 1
```

ml data

```
eid | name | contact
----+------+--------
1   | xyz  | null
```

ve data

```
eid | name | contact
----+------+--------
1   | xyz  | 1
```

ae data

```
eid | gender
----+--------
1   | male
```

I want this result:

```
eid | gender | name | contact
----+--------+------+--------
1   | male   | xyz  | null
```

But I am getting this for now:

```
eid | gender | name | contact | contact
----+--------+------+---------+--------
1   | male   | xyz  | 1       | null
```

I'm using node-mssql driver for querying SQL Server data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join `ve` only if there is no matching row in `ml` and you do it if you add in the `ON` clause the condition `... AND ml.eid IS NULL`.
Also use `COALESCE()` to select the columns from `ml` first and if they don't exist from `ve`:

```
SELECT ae.*, 
       COALESCE(ml.name, ve.name) AS name, 
       COALESCE(ml.contact, ve.contact) AS contact
FROM ae
LEFT JOIN ml ON ae.eid = ml.eid
LEFT JOIN ve ON ae.eid = ve.eid AND ml.eid IS NULL
WHERE ae.eid = 1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1d9c8816fd884a5ba0f6f1e12e9da0f).
Results:

| eid | gender | name | contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | male | xyz | null |

Comment: Prefer `ISNULL` over `COALESCE` in SQL Server for performance reasons

Comment: Thanks @forpas for sharing, useful answer, i know it's very easy, but i was bit new in mssql, so not able to find that solution, thanks again, it's working for me